# Remove empty tags at beginning in Redactor html editor

Tags: php, jquery, html, redactor, redactor.js

I am using Redactor html editor. What i was finding is how to remove empty '`<p></br></p>`' tags at the beginning.It shows when when I click on source code of content.

A similar question was asked in past.
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352130/remove-empty-tags-in-imperavi-redactor)

I have also checked their documentation but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Did you saw this part of the doc http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/clean/#setting-removeEmpty ? and are you using the last version of redactor? And also how do you populate the field? Can you check if the empty paragraph is persisted in your DB, if you use one.

Comment: Could you please check http://jsfiddle.net/swX6V/156/

Comment: You should really update your redactor version, you are using version 8.2.2, dated from january 2013. I tried with the latest version and the issues is solved.

Comment: I found the version on January 2013 couldn't found the latest version. Could you please send me the link or anything where I get new one?

Comment: http://imperavi.com/redactor/

Comment: Yes, It's fixed. Thanks a lot!!